# Generating functions to find a coefficient

Tags: generating-functions

Use generating functions to find the coefficient of $x^{15}$ in $\frac{x^3-5x }{(1-x)^3}$.

Comment: Series expansion:  $$-5 x-15 x^2-29 x^3-47 x^4-69 x^5-95 x^6-125 x^7-159 x^8-197 x^9-239 x^{10}-285 x^{11}-335
   x^{12}-389 x^{13}-447 x^{14}-509 x^{15}+O\left(x^{16}\right)$$

Comment: Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 2):

Notice that $$\frac{1}{(1-x)^3} = \frac{1}{2}\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right) = \frac{1}{2}\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\left(\sum_{n\geqslant 0}x^n\right)=\sum_{n\geqslant 0}\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2}x^n.$$
Write $[x^k]f(x)$ for the coefficient of $x^k$ in the generating function $f$. Then,
$$[x^{15}]\left\{\frac{x^3-5x}{(1-x)^3}\right\}=[x^{12}]\left\{\frac{1}{(1-x)^3}\right\}-5[x^{14}]\left\{\frac{1}{(1-x)^3}\right\}=13\cdot7 - 5\cdot 15\cdot8=-509.$$

Comment: I got it, thank you